# Spring MVC call jsp from sub menu

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a menu in my jsp:

```
<ul class="submenu">
    <li class="">
        <a href="create/wizard">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Wizard
        </a>

        <b class="arrow"></b>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="view/contract">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Contract
        </a>

        <b class="arrow"></b>
    </li>
</ul>
```

2 menus for 2 jsp one is to create one is to view.  My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create/wizard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(Model model) {
    ContractHeader ch = new ContractHeader();
    model.addAttribute("createForm", ch);

    return "wizard";
}    

@RequestMapping(value = "/view/contract", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ViewContract(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contractHeader", new ContractHeader());
    model.addAttribute("ch", this.contractHeaderService.listContractHeaders());

    return "viewcontract";
}
```

First time I login if you go to any of the page it works but let's say I'm in /create/wizard url (http://localhost:8080/ccts/create/wizard) and I go to /view/contract, the url becomes:

```
Wrong: http://localhost:8080/ccts/create/view/contract

Type Status report
messageNot Found
descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
```

when it is supposed to go to

```
Correct: http://localhost:8080/ccts/view/contract
```

the extra "create" is appending to the correct url.  Any idea as to why?

Comment: Try `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/create/view` to create absolute paths in your jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

Change your links to this

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/create/wizard">
    ...
</a>
```

and

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/contract">
    ...
</a>
```